# extracting days from a numpy.timedelta64 value

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am using pandas/python and I have two date time series s1 and s2, that have been generated using the 'to_datetime' function on a field of the df containing dates/times.

When I subtract s1 from s2

> s3 = s2 - s1

I get a series, s3, of type

> timedelta64[ns]

```
0    385 days, 04:10:36
1     57 days, 22:54:00
2    642 days, 21:15:23
3    615 days, 00:55:44
4    160 days, 22:13:35
5    196 days, 23:06:49
6     23 days, 22:57:17
7      2 days, 22:17:31
8    622 days, 01:29:25
9     79 days, 20:15:14
10    23 days, 22:46:51
11   268 days, 19:23:04
12                  NaT
13                  NaT
14   583 days, 03:40:39
```

How do I look at 1 element of the series:

> s3[10]

I get something like this:

> numpy.timedelta64(2069211000000000,'ns')

How do I extract days from s3 and maybe keep them as integers(not so interested in hours/mins etc.)?

Comment: just FYI, about to merge into pandas master this functionaility: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4534 (you can do this on 0.12 and before by: ``s.apply(lambda x: x / np.timedelta64(1,'D'))``

Comment: Even if you're not interested in hours it might be relevant whether 2 days 23:59 is mapped to 2 days or to 3?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You can convert it to a timedelta with a day precision. To extract the integer value of days you divide it with a timedelta of one day.

```
>>> x = np.timedelta64(2069211000000000, 'ns')
>>> days = x.astype('timedelta64[D]')
>>> days / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
23
```

Or, as @PhillipCloud suggested, just `days.astype(int)` since the `timedelta` is just a 64bit integer that is interpreted in various ways depending on the second parameter you passed in (`'D'`, `'ns'`, ...).

You can find more about it [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.datetime.html).

Comment: You can also do `days.item().days` or `days.astype(int)`.

Comment: more recent versions of pandas support a full fledged Timedelta type, see docs here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html

Comment: This is a good candidate for .apply. You can do this in the same line where you compute column values by putting .apply(lambda x: x/np.timedelta64(1,'D')) at the end to apply the conversion at the column level. e.g.  s3=(s1-s2).apply(lambda x: x/np.timedelta64(1,'D')).

Comment: This method `astype('timedelta64[D]')`(about 96ms) is much more efficient than `dt.days.`(about 24s) for 4,000,000 rows.

Answer (score 68):

Use [`dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) to obtain the days attribute as integers.

For eg:

```
In [14]: s = pd.Series(pd.timedelta_range(start='1 days', end='12 days', freq='3000T'))

In [15]: s
Out[15]: 
0    1 days 00:00:00
1    3 days 02:00:00
2    5 days 04:00:00
3    7 days 06:00:00
4    9 days 08:00:00
5   11 days 10:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [16]: s.dt.days
Out[16]: 
0     1
1     3
2     5
3     7
4     9
5    11
dtype: int64
```

More generally - You can use the [`.components`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.dt.components.html) property to access a reduced form of `timedelta`.

```
In [17]: s.dt.components
Out[17]: 
   days  hours  minutes  seconds  milliseconds  microseconds  nanoseconds
0     1      0        0        0             0             0            0
1     3      2        0        0             0             0            0
2     5      4        0        0             0             0            0
3     7      6        0        0             0             0            0
4     9      8        0        0             0             0            0
5    11     10        0        0             0             0            0
```

Now, to get the `hours` attribute:

```
In [23]: s.dt.components.hours
Out[23]: 
0     0
1     2
2     4
3     6
4     8
5    10
Name: hours, dtype: int64
```

Comment: +1 - This is the best way to do this currently since the pandas package has progressed since this question was asked.

Answer (score 10):

Suppose you have a timedelta series:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
z = pd.DataFrame({'a':[datetime.strptime('20150101', '%Y%m%d')],'b':[datetime.strptime('20140601', '%Y%m%d')]})

td_series = (z['a'] - z['b'])
```

One way to convert this timedelta column or series is to cast it to a Timedelta object (pandas 0.15.0+) and then extract the days from the object:

```
td_series.astype(pd.Timedelta).apply(lambda l: l.days)
```

Another way is to cast the series as a timedelta64 in days, and then cast it as an int:

```
td_series.astype('timedelta64[D]').astype(int)
```

Comment: This was is quite fast as compared to other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the date time column in pandas date time by using:

```
## Convert time in pandas date time
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], errors='coerce')
```

Once that is done use the following command to subtract two dates:

```
df["Duration_after subtraction"] = (df['End_Time'] - df['Start_Time']   / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')
```

To convert into hour use 'h' instead of 'm'