# Python: Convert timedelta to int in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I would like to create a column in a pandas data frame that is an integer representation of the number of days in a timedelta column.  Is it possible to use 'datetime.days' or do I need to do something more manual?

**timedelta column**

> 7 days, 23:29:00

**day integer column**

> 7

Comment: Have you tried to use `timedelta.days`?

Answer (score 275):

The Series class has a [`pandas.Series.dt` accessor object](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) with several
useful datetime attributes, including [`dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html). Access this attribute via:

```
timedelta_series.dt.days
```

You can also get the `seconds` and `microseconds` attributes in the same way.

Comment: I like this comment for the simplicity and not requiring import of another library.

Comment: Make sue you use this on a Series.  It does not work on a DataFrame.

Answer (score 78):

You could do this, where `td` is your series of timedeltas.  The division converts the nanosecond deltas into day deltas, and the conversion to int drops to whole days.

```
import numpy as np

(td / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Also after 15 more minutes of searching I found this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215317/extracting-days-from-a-numpy-timedelta64-value

Comment: what is the `/` for between `td` and `np`?

Comment: It's the timedelta64 division operator. Dividing td by a 1 day time delta is results in the (possibly fractional) number of days represented in td. Not required in this case but it's really useful if say you want to work out how many 15 minute intervals td represents

Answer (score 45):

Timedelta objects have read-only instance attributes `.days`, `.seconds`, and `.microseconds`.

Comment: No `.hours` or `.minutes` though, so you will need to do some math if you want values in those units.

Answer (score 22):

If the question isn't just "how to access an integer form of the timedelta?" but "how to convert the timedelta column in the dataframe to an int?" the answer might be a little different. In addition to the `.dt.days` accessor you need either `df.astype` or `pd.to_numeric`

Either of these options should help:

```
df['tdColumn'] = pd.to_numeric(df['tdColumn'].dt.days, downcast='integer')
```

or

```
df['tdColumn'] = df['tdColumn'].dt.days.astype('int16')
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but I got ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer because there are nans in the pandas series. Do you know who to sort this out???

Comment: The second option worked for me and the date values were of type `timedelta64[ns]`. If your dates are NaN, first convert them to datetime using the pandas `to_datetime` function, then use the second option above. For more details checkout [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html?highlight=to_datetime)

Answer (score 5):

A great way to do this is

`dif_in_days = dif.days`
(where `dif` is the difference between dates)

Comment: this answer is similar to a previous one, consider adding a comment instead of answering again

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this is by

```
df["DateColumn"] = (df["DateColumn"]).dt.days
```

Comment: this solution is not different from already proposed ones.

Comment: Yes you are right, I am only pointing out the easiest amongst the solutions I know