# Multiplying pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 csv files with the same structure but differing lengths:
a.csv

```
2000-01-14,50.94,51.04,49.83,49.94,2.18M,-1.61%
2000-01-18,49.18,49.32,48.39,48.53,3.03M,-2.81%
2000-01-19,48.63,49.37,47.7,47.89,2.49M,-1.33%
2000-01-20,47.98,48.03,46.31,47.43,2.46M,-0.96%
```

and b.csv

```
2000-01-14,1.0261,1.0273,1.0111,1.0128,-1.23%,
2000-01-17,1.0128,1.0149,1.0069,1.0118,-0.10%,
2000-01-18,1.0123,1.0143,1.0072,1.0131,0.13%,
2000-01-19,1.0139,1.0166,1.0086,1.0122,-0.09%,
2000-01-20,1.0137,1.0189,1.0072,1.0175,0.52%,
```

I would like to create a new file with the values of columns 1-4 multiplied with each other. Column 0 (the date) should be the same as in the file with the lower nr of entries. Columns 5 and 6 can be discarded.

I read in the files with the following code:

```
a = pd.read_csv("a.csv", index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True, header=None, skiprows=1, delimiter=',', names=['Date', 'Close','Open', 'High','Low', 'Vol.','Change'])
b = pd.read_csv("b.csv", index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True, header=None, skiprows=1, delimiter=',', names=['Date', 'Close','Open', 'High','Low', 'Vol.','Change'])
```

Now I thought I could multiply using the mul method, but 
`c = a.mul(b, axis = 0)` gives an error `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type str`
I read in [this SO reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707530/pandas-multiplying-dataframes) to do
`a.Close = (a.Close.values / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int)` before the multiplication, but it didn't work: `TypeError: ufunc divide cannot use operands with types dtype('float64') and dtype('<m8[D]')`
Doing a simple `c = (a.Close * b.Close)` seems to work somehow:

```
Date
2000-01-17          NaN
2000-01-18    49.784914
2000-01-19    49.305957
2000-01-20    48.637326
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

But I am not sure if the result is still a pandas dataframe and how I add the other columns to that. However I am pretty sure this should be very easy, could you point me to the right direction?
Thank you!

Comment: You'll get all types of strange things happening multiplying two dataframes together - timestamps etc getting in the way. I would suggest joining the dataframes on a given key (e.g. date) and then multiplying whichever columns you want together, as you've managed above. You can also use the ```to_frame()``` method to turn your series in ```c``` back in to a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to morganics comment I (after googling, being not familiar with python) I came up with the following solution:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv("a.csv", index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True, header=None, skiprows=1, delimiter=',', names=['Date', 'Close','Open', 'High','Low', 'Vol.','Change'])
b = pd.read_csv("b.csv", index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True, header=None, skiprows=1, delimiter=',', names=['Date', 'Close','Open', 'High','Low', 'Vol.','Change'])

c= a.join(b, lsuffix='_a', rsuffix='_b')

# create new columns with multiplied values
c['Close'] = c.Close_a * c.Close_b
c['Open'] = c.Open_a * c.Open_b
c['High'] = c.High_a * c.High_b
c['Low'] = c.Low_a * c.Low_b

# create subset with new data and round
d = c[['Close','Open', 'High', 'Low']]
d = d.round({'Close':2,'Open':2, 'High':2, 'Low':2})
d.to_csv("d.csv", sep=',', header=True)
```

Which gives d.csv:

```
Date,Close,Open,High,Low
2000-01-18,49.78,50.03,48.74,49.17
2000-01-19,49.31,50.19,48.11,48.47
2000-01-20,48.64,48.94,46.64,48.26
```

Neat :) Thank you very much!