# pandas dataframe groupby mean No numeric types to aggregate

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df` `groupby` result,

```
df_group = df.groupby(['code', 'year_month']).count()

                                 days_outstanding  
code      year_month                            
1            2016-10                            4  
             2016-12                            1  
             2017-01                            1
```

when I tried,

```
df_days = df.groupby(['code', 'year_month'])['days_outstanding'].mean().reset_index(name='avg_days_outanding')
```

to get the average days for each group for column `days_outstanding`, but I got the following error,

```
 pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

I am wondering how to fix it.

UPDATE

```
print(df['days_outstanding'].head().apply(type))

436     <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timedelta'>
437     <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timedelta'>
839     <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timedelta'>
2447    <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timedelta'>
3844    <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timedelta'>
```

the `df` is like,

```
       code    year_month   days_outstanding
436    1       2016-10      0
437    1       2016-10      0
839    1       2016-10      0
2447   1       2016-10      0
3844   1       2016-12      0
9157   1       2017-01      0
```

Comment: I think `['days_outstanding']` is not numeric, what return `print(df['days_outstanding'].head().apply(type))` ?

Comment: @jezrael I have edited my op to show the print result

Comment: convert your `days_outstanding` column to integer via `df['days_outstanding'] = df['days_outstanding'].dt.days` beforehand.

Comment: @jpp that works perfectly, thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Convert timedelta to int in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646200/python-convert-timedelta-to-int-in-a-dataframe)