# Create a new column in pandas using a value of a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First of all, this is not a duplicate! I have searched in several SO questions as well as the Pandas doc, and I have not found anything conclusive!To create a new column with a row value, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789445/pandas-make-new-column-from-string-slice-of-another-column) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53286849/create-a-new-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-values-found-on-a-previous-ro)!

Imagine I have the following table, **opening an `.xls`** and I create a dataframe with it. As this is a small example created from the real proble, I created this simple Excel table which can be easily reproduceable:

[image: Table]

What I want now is to find the row that has `"Population Month Year"` (I will be looking at different `.xls`, so the structure is the same: population, month and year.

```
xls='population_example.xls'
sheet_name='Sheet1'
df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=sheet_name, header=0, skiprows=2)
df
```

What I thought is:

1. Get the value of that row with `startswith`
2. Create a column, pythoning that value and getting the month and year value.

I have tried several things similar to this:

```
dff=df[s.str.startswith('Population')]
dff
```

But errors won't stop coming. In this above's code error, specifically:

> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

I have several guesses:

- I am not understanding properly how `Series`in pandas work, even though reading the doc. I did not even think on using them, but the `startswith`looks like the thing I am looking for.
- If I handle this properly, I might have a `NaN error`, but I cannot use `df.dropna()`yet, as I would lose that row value (`Population April 2017`)!

**Edit:**

The problem on using this:

`df[df['Area'].str.startswith('Population')]` Is that it will check the `na values`.

And this:

`df['Area'].str.startswith('Population')`

Will give me a true/false/na set of values, which I am not sure how I can use.

Comment: what is `s` here? I think you want `df[df['Area'].str.startswith('Population')]`

Comment: But first of all reformat your question in a decent format, dont post [pictures of your code/data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). We cannot copy and paste that to reproduce an answer. And how would your expected output look like?

Comment: Try: `df[df['Area'].str.startswith('Population'), na=False]` To fix your `NaN` problem

Comment: I am opening a `.xls`. I will transform it into a `.csv`so you can open it! This is a small problem from the real one, which has a more complex table, etc, so that is why I did not want to bother with extra info @Erfan . omw to edit!

Comment: We don't need a csv. Just post an example dataset here, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for more information.

Comment: Please have a look at [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: On my way! Thanks for all the feedback! Not really used to ask about pandas @Erfan . The starts with did the trick to get me the whole row!

Comment: I posted the solution! If you want, post that same solution yourself, and I shall accept it, upvote it and delete mine as you made me get there! @Erfan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Erfan , I got to the solution:

Using properly the line of code in the comments and not like I was trying, I managed to:

`dff=df[df['Area'].str.startswith('Population', na=False)]
dff`

Which would output: `Population and household forecasts, 2016 to 20...  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN`

Now I can access this value like

`value=dff.iloc[0][0]
 value`

To get the string I was looking for: `'Population and household forecasts, 2016 to 2041, prepared by .id , the population experts, April 2019.'`
And I can python around with this to create the desired column. Thank you!

Comment: You might want to use: `df.loc[df['Area'].str.startswith('Population', na=False), 'Area'].iat[0]` Which will give you the value as well

Comment: That is actually much better and optimal! Thank you so much for the patience and goot attitude towards the question! @Erfan

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame({'Area': [f'Whatever{i+1}' for i in range(3)] + [np.nan, 'Population April 2017.'],
              'Population': [3867, 1675, 1904, np.nan, np.nan]}).to_excel('population_example.xls', index=False)

df = pd.read_excel('population_example.xls').fillna('')

population_date = df[df.Area.str.startswith('Population')].Area.values[0].lstrip('Population ').rstrip('.').split()
```

Result:

```
['April', '2017']
```

Or (if Population Month Year is always on the last row):

```
df.iloc[-1, 0].lstrip('Population ').rstrip('.').split()
```