# Django convert timedelta to integer in annotation

Tags: django

I'm annotating the difference between two dates then aggregating the rounded average. The problem is that the difference between the two dates is a `datetime.timedelta` so I am getting the error:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type interval to numeric

How can can I use the integer `days_to_pay.days` in the `Avg()`?

```
def aggregate_ar_detail(self):
    queryset = self.annotate(
        days_to_pay=Case(
            When(Q(date_paid__isnull=False), then=F('date_paid') - F('date_trans')),
            default=None,
        )
    ).aggregate(
        avg_days=Round(Avg('days_to_pay')),
    )
```

I've tried specifying the output field on the annotation a `models.IntegerField()` but it causes:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta'

Comment: Do the answers here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646200/python-convert-timedelta-to-int-in-a-dataframe Honestly I don't know if this is a duplicate so not flagged yet

Comment: @ggdx same language and same problem but completely different solutions. Not to mention using `.days` (the solution from your link) was included in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed to get it working with [`ExtractDay`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#datefield-extracts)

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractDay

def aggregate_ar_detail(self):
    queryset = self.annotate(
        days_to_pay=Case(
            When(Q(date_paid__isnull=False), then=F('date_paid') - F('date_trans')),
            default=None,
        )
    ).aggregate(
        avg_days=Round(Avg(ExtractDay('days_to_pay'))),
    )
```

Comment: Just ran into a similar problem, when I wanted to convert a duration from seconds to minutes. In order to use the Extract-method, I had to specify an output field though: `self.annotate(duration_minutes=ExpressionWrapper(Max('date_time') - Min('date_time'), output_field=DurationField())`. I didn't run your code, but could it be, the ExpressionWrapper is missing in your answer? (Could of course also be, that the `F()-F()` has a different return value than `Min()-Max()`)