# Filter data based on intervals in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I have following model:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    due = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    max_days_before_due = models.IntegerField()
```

I would like to filter out instances or rows that are past this due, ie. when `due` minus `max_days_before_due` is in the past. I am using this query:

```py
current_date = timezone.now()

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    counted_days=Case(
        When(
            due__isnull=False,
            then=ExtractDay(F('due')-current_date)
        ),
        default=0,
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
).filter(
    max_days_before_due__lt=F('counted_days')
)
```

I am receiving this error:

```
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
django_1    |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django_1    | django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function pg_catalog.timezone(unknown, interval) does not exist
django_1    | LINE 1: ... '2020-08-26T15:03:11.111165+00:00'::timestamptz) AT TIME ZO...
django_1    |                                                              ^
django_1    | HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

When I delete the subtration from the annotation, the error does not show, but I need to be able to count the timedelta. Otherwise if I set the `due` to, let's say, `2020-08-30` and `current_date` is `2020-08-26` it returns 30 in the `counted_days` field instead of 4.

I've been trying to use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57691444/django-convert-timedelta-to-integer-in-annotation) and [these docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#datefield-extracts) as reference. I am using PostgreSQL in version 10 and Django in version 1.11, Python 3.4.

**EDIT**

It seems that this task should be pretty straightforward using plain SQL:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT DATE '2020-08-26' + 10;
  ?column?
------------
 2020-09-05
```

Maybe there's an easier way of doing this.

Comment: `F('max_days_before_due')` will be an *integer* type, where as the `current_date` is a `datetime`, That could be the reason

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Sorry, I've messed the variables in the question. I'm subtracting two dates. so this shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: I think, it is better to use [**`Now(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Now) than `timezone.now()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more hours into debugging I managed to discover what was the issue and how to solve it, so here we go.

The field I kept in my database was a "timestamp with timezone".

I managed to reproduce the error in plain sql in postgres. When selecting a `TIMESTAMP` and subtracting an integer from it I got the same error as showed in my Django logs:

```
postgres=# SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-08-26 01:01:00.123456-01:00'  + 10 > DATE '2020-09-01';
ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone + integer
LINE 1: ...ECT TIMESTAMP '2020-08-26 01:01:00.123456-01:00'  + 10 > DAT...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

As I've said in the update to my question, adding or subtracting integers from date objects is fairly easy:

```
postgres=# SELECT DATE '2020-08-26 01:01:00.123456-01:00'  + 10 > DATE '2020-09-01';
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

This suggested using a proper casting in the annotation:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(due_date=Case(
    When(
        due__isnull=False,
        then=Cast('due', output_field=DateField()) - F('max_days_before_due')
    ),
    default=None,
    output_field=DateTimeField()
).filter(due_date__gt=current_date)
```

And viola:

```
pprint(my_model_query.values('due', 'max_days_before_due', 'due_date')))
```

Returns:

```
<MyModelQuerySet [{'due': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 20, 9, 31, 25, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'max_days_before_due': 30, 'due_date': datetime.date(2020, 7, 21)}]>
```