# Different color gradation for scatter plot depending on time (Matplotlib)

Tags: datetime, matplotlib, data-visualization, scatter-plot, colorbar

I have a data set that is shaped like below.

```
import pandas as pd

catalog=pd.read_table("Catalog/MainshockCatalog.txt", sep="\t", 
                  names=["Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Min", "Sec", "Lat",
                        "Lon", "Depth", "Mag"])
catalog
```

[image: catalog dataframe]

I drew the map of each event using `Axes3D` and the coordinate was given as columns `Lat`, `Lon`, and `Depth` of `catalog` DataFrame.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(30, 20))
ax=fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x=catalog["Lat"]
y=catalog["Lon"]
z=-catalog["Depth"]

ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='k', marker='o', s=50, alpha=0.1, facecolors='none')
ax.scatter(x[0], y[0], z[0], c='b', marker='*', s=1500, label="$M_L$ 5.4 Mainshock")
ax.scatter(x[2395], y[2395], z[2395], c='r', marker='*', s=1500, label="$M_L$ 4.6 Aftershock")

ax.set_xlabel('Latitude ($^\circ$)', fontsize=30, labelpad=30)
ax.set_ylabel('Longitude ($^\circ$)', fontsize=30, labelpad=30)
ax.set_zlabel('Depth (km)', fontsize=30, labelpad=20)

ax.set_zticklabels(['8','7','6','5','4','3','2'])

ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
ax.zaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)

plt.legend(prop={'size': 30})
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot looks like below.
[image: 3D hypocenter plot]

In this figure, the color of every dot is same. However, I want it to be smoothly differ with gradation as associated time (`Year`, `Month`, `Day`, `Hour`, `Min`, `Sec`) increases with the colorbar. The example would be like below (although color changes as depth, not time for this example).

[image: benchmark example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been doing some tests and I have gotten this to work.

1. Create a new column on your `catalog` dataframe with the time information in `datetime` format. To do so use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```py
collect['DateHour'] =  pd.to_datetime(collect['Year'].astype(str) \
+ '/' + collect['Month'].astype(str) + '/' + \
collect['Day'].astype(str) \ 
+ 'T' + collect['Hour'].astype(str)+ ':' + collect['Min'].astype(str) \
 ':' + collect['Sec'].astype(str))
```

2A. You can use this new column to plot it straightly as a color, by indicating it in the `c` parameter of your `ax.scatter` function, but it might not make for a very pretty colorbar.

2B. Or if you want to have a colobar indicating for example a time difference in days to a particular date-time (for example your first date in the data), you can create a new column by simply making the difference of `collect['DateHour']` column to the date-time instance properly formatted (or taken from `collect['DateHour']`), and then transform the time delta to your desired unit to measure the time increment. You can see [here some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646200/python-convert-timedelta-to-int-in-a-dataframe) on how to transform `timedelta64` to a convenient time measure. In this example it is transformed to days:

```py
collect['dt_days'] = (collect['DateHour']-pd.to_datetime('2002-02-03T13:56:03.172')) \
/ np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

3B. Use this column by indicating it in the `c` parameter of your `ax.scatter`

Comment: Your suggestion was very successful. Thanks!