# python - how to count down days until Birthday (between two dates)

Tags: python, date, datetime

The task I was given is to create a program that will check if the current date is your birthday. If it is, print "Happy Birthday!". If not then output how many days left till your birthday.

I have been struggling with this task, I think I have got it working, but how do I remove the comma "," and the time "0:00:00" output from the result?

I only want it to display the number of days and the word days.

INPUT:
1989
6
21

DESIRED OUTPUT (at time/date of asking question!):
349 days

NOT: 349 days, 0:00:00

Hope that is clear and thanks in advance!

--

So far I have:

```
import datetime


today = datetime.date.today()

user_birth_year = int(input("Enter year of birth i.e. 1989: "))
user_birth_month = int(input("Enter month of birth i.e. for June enter 6: "))
user_birth_day = int(input("Enter day of birth i.e. for 21st enter 21: "))

my_birthday = datetime.date(today.year, user_birth_month, user_birth_day)
if my_birthday == today:
    print("Happy Birthday!")
else:
    if my_birthday < today:
        my_birthday = my_birthday.replace(year=today.year + 1)
        days_until_birthday = my_birthday - today
        print(days_until_birthday)

    else:
        days_until_birthday = my_birthday - today
        print(days_until_birthday)
```

Comment: Change `days_until_birthday` to `days_until_birthday.days`. Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646200/python-convert-timedelta-to-int-in-a-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

This is included in any tutorial on `datetime`.  If you want only the days, then access the `days` attribute.

```
else:
    days_until_birthday = my_birthday - today
    print(days_until_birthday.days, "days")
```

Comment: Yes I have realised that I can access the attribute from the date object as you said.

I did this and it works, I thought I had tried it before |: maybe I need a tea break :)

Comment: Tea break is always a good idea before posting here.  I took at least three breaks before each of my questions.  :-)   Since this is a problem solved directly by following the documentation, I suggest that you simply delete the question.