# Converting datetime to date (Difference in Integer or Number format)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have multiple columns with datetime format "14-09-2021 12:00:00 AM". I have converted them to date with the below code.

```
df['Column1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column1']).dt.date
df['Column2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column2']).dt.date
```

Intention is to take the difference between the two columns to identify the difference in days. When I take the difference `df['diff']=df['Column1']-df['Column2']` I get the result as say "- 39 days" and not jus "- 39" (Image added below for clarity)

[image]

Intention is to get the difference in integer or number format (i.e just 39 and not 39 days), I'm not sure on how to go about this or when I have erred in the above code.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Like the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42247228/15497888) recommends you can grab just the days through the dt accessor -> `df['diff'] = (df['Column1'] - df['Column2']).dt.days`

Comment: You could add [Series.abs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) to get the absolute value if needing all positive numbers`df['diff'] = (df['Column1'] - df['Column2']).dt.days.abs()`

Comment: @HenryEcker I tried the above code but got an error ```TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'datetime.date'```

Comment: It works fine pandas 1.3.5. (I used this DataFrame `df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['2021-01-09', '2021-01-09'], 'Column2': ['2022-08-31', '2022-01-09']})` to start with and ran your conversion code to change the dtype of each column) What version are you using?

Comment: @HenryEcker I'm using pandas '1.2.4'

Comment: Since I can't see your code I don't know where your mistake is, but the only way I can reproduce the error is calling `df['Column1'].abs()` ( _i.e._ calling the `abs` function directly on a datetime column). You need to take the difference of dates to get a timedelta _then_ you can take the `abs`. The complete code in my comment above -> `df['diff'] = (df['Column1'] - df['Column2']).dt.days.abs()` works (even in 1.2.4) on my end.

Comment: @HenryEcker ```df['diff']=df['diff'].dt.days``` did the trick, thank you for providing the above references.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `df['diff'] = df['diff'].astype(int)`