# Lengths of overlapping time ranges listed by rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, python-datetime

I am using pandas version 1.0.5

The example dataframe below lists time intervals, recorded over three days, and I seek where some time intervals overlap **every** day.

[image: Interim- for illustration]

For example,
one of the overlapping time across all the three dates (yellow highlighted) is 1:16 - 2:13. The other (blue highlighted) would be 18:45 - 19:00

So my expected output would be like: `[57,15]` because

- 57 - Minutes between 1:16 - 2:13.
- 15 - Minutes between 18:45 - 19:00

Please use this generator of the input dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
dat1 = [
    ['2023-12-27','2023-12-27 00:00:00','2023-12-27 02:14:00'],
    ['2023-12-27','2023-12-27 03:16:00','2023-12-27 04:19:00'],
    ['2023-12-27','2023-12-27 18:11:00','2023-12-27 20:13:00'],
    ['2023-12-28','2023-12-28 01:16:00','2023-12-28 02:14:00'],
    ['2023-12-28','2023-12-28 02:16:00','2023-12-28 02:28:00'],
    ['2023-12-28','2023-12-28 02:30:00','2023-12-28 02:56:00'],
    ['2023-12-28','2023-12-28 18:45:00','2023-12-28 19:00:00'],
    ['2023-12-29','2023-12-29 01:16:00','2023-12-29 02:13:00'],
    ['2023-12-29','2023-12-29 04:16:00','2023-12-29 05:09:00'],
    ['2023-12-29','2023-12-29 05:11:00','2023-12-29 05:14:00'],
    ['2023-12-29','2023-12-29 18:00:00','2023-12-29 19:00:00']
       ]
df = pd.DataFrame(dat1,columns = ['date','Start_tmp','End_tmp'])
df["Start_tmp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Start_tmp"])
df["End_tmp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["End_tmp"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution uses:

- numpy, no uncommon Python modules, so using Python 1.0.5 you should, hopefully, be in the clear,
- no nested loops to care for speed issues with growing dataset,

Method:

- Draw the landscape of overlaps
- Then select the overlaps corresponding to the number of documented days,
- Finally describe the overlaps in terms of their lengths

Number of documented days: (as in [Python: Convert timedelta to int in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25646200/12846804))

```
n = 1 + ( max(df['End_tmp']) - min(df['Start_tmp']) ).days
n
3
```

Additive landscape:

```
# initial flat whole-day landcape (height: 0)
L = np.zeros(24*60, dtype='int')
# add up ranges: (reused @sammywemmy's perfect formula for time of day in minutes)
for start, end in zip(df['Start_tmp'].dt.hour.mul(60) + df['Start_tmp'].dt.minute,  # Start_tmp timestamps expressed in minutes
                      df['End_tmp'].dt.hour.mul(60)   + df['End_tmp'].dt.minute):   # End_tmp timestamps expressed in minutes
    L[start:end+1] += 1

plt.plot(L)
plt.hlines(y=[2,3],xmin=0,xmax=1400,colors=['green','red'], linestyles='dashed')
plt.xlabel('time of day (minutes)')
plt.ylabel('time range overlaps')
```

[image: additive landscape]
*(Please excuse the typo: these are obviously minutes, not seconds)*

Keep only overlaps over **all** days: (red line, n=3)

```
# Reduce heights <n to 0 because not overlaping every day
L[L<n]=0
# Simplify all greater values to 1 because only their presence matters
L[L>0]=1
# Now only overlaps are highlighted
# (Actually this latest line is disposable, provided we filter all but the overlaps of rank n. Useful only if you were to include lower overlaps)
```

Extract overlap ranges and their lengths

```
# Highlight edges of overlaping intervals
D = np.diff(L)
# Describe overlaps as ranges
R = list(zip([a[0]   for a in np.argwhere(D>0)],  # indices where overlaps *begin*, with scalar indices instead of arrays
             [a[0]-1 for a in np.argwhere(D<0)])) # indices where overlaps *end*, with scalar indices instead of arrays
R
[(75, 132), (1124, 1139)]
```

```
# Finally their lengths
[b-a for a,b in R]
```

Final output: `[57, 15]`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are only interested in the hours and minutes, and not the entire timestamp. If my assumption is correct, you can execute a range join with [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to get your results:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd
A=(df
   .assign(
       start=df.Start_tmp.dt.hour.mul(60)+ df.Start_tmp.dt.minute,
       end=df.End_tmp.dt.hour.mul(60)+df.End_tmp.dt.minute)
   )
(A
.conditional_join(
    A,
    ('start','start','>'),
    ('end','end','<'),
    df_columns=['start','end'],
    right_columns=None)
.pipe(lambda df: df.end-df.start)
)

0    15
1    57
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Interesting solution, if I understood correctly, OP wants the minimum interval overlapping on every day of the dataframe: on the 27, 28, 29. The given `conditional_join` gives only inclusion if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @L.Meyer This matches the expected output of 57, 15 right? OP over to you