# Accessing .seconds or .days attribute of timedelta data in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, timedelta

I would like to convert data of type `timedelta64` in a `Pandas` `Series` into `timedelta64` to hours.

To do this I'd like to access the `.seconds` or `.days` attribute of a `timedelta64` so that I can convert these unit myself [as per this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2119499/2694260).

However, when I select the data using `df['col']` I get an `attribute error` when I try to use `.seconds` or `.days` despite its `dtype` being `<m8[ns]` (which I believe represents `timedelta64`).

Is there another step that I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That question is referring to the built-in Python `timedelta` object, while you are dealing with a numpy array of `timedelta64` values.  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215317/extracting-days-from-a-numpy-timedelta64-value) - you can convert to hours or seconds using astype.

```
td.astype('timedelta64[D]')
td.astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

Alternatively, you could divide by the appropriate unit.

```
td / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
td / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
```

Comment: Thanks, both approaches worked. Is there any difference between the two methods or is it purely a matter or personal preference? @chrisb

Comment: @Bprodz - couldn't tell you for sure, but both should give the same answer.  On some test data, astype was a little faster (and probably communicates the intent more clearly) so that may be the way to go.