# Do not need the 'days' part for difference between dates field in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below dataframes -

```
            A          B
one 2014-01-01 2014-02-28
two 2014-02-03 2014-03-01
```

Now when I try -

```
df['C'] = df['A'] - df['B']
```

I get the below result -

```
            A          B        C
one 2014-01-01 2014-02-28 -58 days
two 2014-02-03 2014-03-01 -26 days
```

But I want my result to be as below without the 'days' part because I want to export the data into a sql table directly -

```
        A          B        C
one 2014-01-01 2014-02-28 -58
two 2014-02-03 2014-03-01 -26
```

What is the easiest way to get that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just divide the `np.timedelta64` by 1 day:

```
In [21]:

df['C'] = (df['A'] - df['B'])/(np.timedelta64(1,'D'))
df
Out[21]:
  index          A          B   C
0   one 2014-01-01 2014-02-28 -58
1   two 2014-02-03 2014-03-01 -26
```

See related: [extracting days from a numpy.timedelta64 value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215317/extracting-days-from-a-numpy-timedelta64-value)