# how to extract days as integers from a timedelta64[ns] object in python

Tags: python, timedelta

I have a pandas dataframe with a column like:

```
In [96]: data['difference']
Out[96]: 
0                 NaT
1     1 days 21:34:30
2     0 days 16:57:36
3     0 days 00:16:51
4     0 days 15:52:38
5     0 days 14:19:34
6     0 days 02:54:46
7     1 days 04:21:28
8     0 days 01:58:55
9     0 days 10:30:35
10    0 days 07:53:04
....
Name: difference, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I want to create next to it a column with integers corresponding to the days values in this column.

Comment: I just want a column like 1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0

Comment: i think you can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215317/extracting-days-from-a-numpy-timedelta64-value

Comment: I already looked at it but the solution days.astype(int) does not work for me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should convert your `timedelta64[ns]` type to `float64` representing days:

```
data['difference'].astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

Comment: This method `astype('timedelta64[D]')`(about 96ms) is much more efficient than `dt.days.`(about 24s) for 4,000,000 rows.

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76119709/10197418): `.astype('timedelta64[D]')` is **not supported anymore** in newer versions of pandas.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `dt.days` to extract just days from your series,

```
df.difference
Out[117]: 
0   -1 days +00:00:05
1                 NaT
2   -1 days +00:00:05
3     1 days 00:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

df.difference.dt.days
Out[118]: 
0    -1
1   NaN
2    -1
3     1
dtype: float64
```

All other component extracts,

```
dr
Out[93]: 
0   -1 days +00:00:05
1                 NaT
2     1 days 02:04:05
3     1 days 00:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

dr.dt.components
Out[95]: 
   days  hours  minutes  seconds  milliseconds  microseconds  nanoseconds
0    -1      0        0        5             0             0            0
1   NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN           NaN           NaN          NaN
2     1      2        4        5             0             0            0
3     1      0        0        0             0             0            0
```

Comment: This method is pretty slow. In contrast, the method `astype('timedelta64[D]')`(about 96ms) is much more efficient than `dt.days.`(about 24s) for 4,000,000 rows.

Answer (score 3):

According to [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion) documentation, you can extract days using `astype` method of `timedelta64` object and the result is of type `float64`.

```
data['difference'].astype('timedelta64[D]')
```