# converting timedeltas to days error

Tags: python, pandas

I've had problems converting `timedeltas` to an `int (days)`.

```
df.FIN = pd.to_datetime(df.FIN, errors = 'coerce')
df.START = pd.to_datetime(df.START, errors = 'coerce')
df["FIN-START"] = df["FIN"] - df["START"]
```

*** input: ***

```
0    0 days 00:00:00
1   89 days 19:41:05
2    0 days 00:00:00
3    0 days 00:00:00
4    0 days 00:00:00
...
Name: FIN-START, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

*** error-causing line: ***

```
df["days"] = df["FIN-START"].apply(lambda td: td.days)
```

*** error: ***

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.timedelta64' object has no attribute 'days'
```

Comment: I think the page here answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215317/extracting-days-from-a-numpy-timedelta64-value

Comment: thanks - that worked. I had previously tried a different portion of that answer. I'm unclear why td.days doesn't work but ok with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

for each of the elements in the `Series`, convert the `timedelta` to `timedelta[D]` in the form of, for example, `94 days`. Then, just take it `astype` int.

```
df["days"] = df["FIN-START"].apply(lambda td: td.astype('timedelta64[D]').astype(int))
```