# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'

Tags: python, attributeerror, timedelta

I have a column 'delta' in a dataframe dtype: timedelta64[ns], calculated by subcontracting one date from another. I am trying to return the number of days as a float by using this code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
df['days'] = float(df['delta'].days)
```

but I receive this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: You're calling a method on a Series (which is what a DataFrame column is) and not the values within it. Are you sure that the `dtype` of that column is already some sort of `datetime`?

Comment: maybe you [need to convert it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215317/extracting-days-from-a-numpy-timedelta64-value)

Comment: Yes - 
Name: delta, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While subtracting the dates you should use the following code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ pd.Timestamp('20010101'), pd.Timestamp('20040605') ])
(df.loc[0]-df.loc[1]).astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

So basically use `.astype('timedelta64[D]')` on the subtracted column.

Comment: this didn't work for me - its just sets all values to 0 (because time < 1 day); but I am on an older pandas version so who knows whats going on

Answer (score 49):

DataFrame column is a Series, and for Series you need dt.accessor to calculate days (if you are using a newer Pandas version). You can see docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html)

So, you need to change:

```
df['days'] = float(df['delta'].days)
```

To

```
df['days'] = float(df['delta'].dt.days)
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: This answered the question for me.  The only addition I required was that dt refers to the datetime package so import datetime as dt.  Perhaps this is obvious for experienced Pythonistas but I guess those who are searching for this might not be that experienced

Comment: specifically, "dt" DOES NOT refer to the datetime module - but an 'accessor' for 'datetimelike' objects of the Series values.  the link provided explains it perfectly.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html
that functionality is very, very subtle in my opinion, and i thank those for posting it.
i used it to make a mask for datetimes that matched a certain weekday value.