# computing the Cumulative Sum, where Sum can be reset by a condition

Tags: python, pandas

[Pandas DataFrame, computing the Time Difference between one row and other row which satisfies a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57531331/pandas-dataframe-computing-the-time-difference-between-one-row-and-other-row-wh)

Similar to this Question,
Given,
[image]

I would like to find the 'Cumulative Sum  Of Occurrence Master Event' , and 'Cumulative Sum  Of Occurrence Event A ' and Event B in between the Master Event.
In other words, the instance when Master Event Occour, Cummulative Sum of Event A is reset to Zero.

Sample output is as follows,

[image]

Sample Input code by @Jon Strutz

```
 import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2019] * 10,
                       'month': [8] * 10,
                       'day': [16] * 10,
                       'hour': [12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13],
                       'minute': [50, 52, 53, 57, 0, 3,4,5,13,21]})

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(df), columns=['Time_Stamp'])
df['Event_Master'] = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 1,0]
df['Event_B']      = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ,0, 1, 0, 0,1]
```

And expected output could be like

```
df['Event_Master_Out'] = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1 ,1, 1, 1, 2,2]
df['Event_B_Out'] =      [0, 0, 0, 1, 1 ,1, 2, 2, 0,1]
```

Comment: df.Master.cumsum()

Comment: You don't even have an Event A column in your sample input. And please paste your sample input and output in text, not pictures

Comment: @Code Different ,  respecting your comment I have made the changes in the Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and output is used for [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df['Event_Master_Out'] = df['Event_Master'].cumsum()
df['Event_B_Out'] = df.groupby('Event_Master_Out')['Event_B'].cumsum()
print (df)
           Time_Stamp  Event_Master  Event_B  Event_Master_Out  Event_B_Out
0 2019-08-16 12:50:00             0        0                 0            0
1 2019-08-16 12:52:00             0        0                 0            0
2 2019-08-16 12:53:00             1        0                 1            0
3 2019-08-16 12:57:00             0        1                 1            1
4 2019-08-16 13:00:00             0        0                 1            1
5 2019-08-16 13:03:00             0        0                 1            1
6 2019-08-16 13:04:00             0        1                 1            2
7 2019-08-16 13:05:00             0        0                 1            2
8 2019-08-16 13:13:00             1        0                 2            0
9 2019-08-16 13:21:00             0        1                 2            1
```